# Typecast Double to Text in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, casting

I'm trying to execute a SQL query in PowerShell that pulls out the dump and enters the output data in Excel. The following is the PS Code that I had used and it populates only few cells in the Excel and fails to populate the cells that contains the datatype as Float, Double, Int32, etc.

```
$servers = "VINESH-PC"
$query =
@'
SELECT top 100 * FROM PROFILE_DUMP 
'@

$Filename='SQL_DUMP'
# Open Excel
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl = $xl.Workbooks.Add()
$ExcelWorkSheet = $xl.Worksheets.Add()
$xl.Visible = $true
$rowCount = 2
foreach ($s in $servers)
    {
        $results =  invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $s -Query $query
        foreach ($r in $results)
            {
                # set up col and server info
                $ColCount = 1
                for ($i=1; $i -le $r.ItemArray.Count; $i ++)
                    {
                        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowCount,$ColCount).Numberformat='@'
                        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowCount,$ColCount).Value2 = $r.ItemArray[$i-1]
                        $ColCount ++
                    }
                $rowCount ++
            }
    }
# Add Header to Sheet
$headers = $results | Get-Member -Membertype property
$h = 1
foreach ($header in $headers)
    {
        $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,$h).Value2 = $header.name
        $h ++
    }
## Format Excel Spreadsheet
$listObject = $ExcelWorkSheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange, $null,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes,$null)
$listObject.Name = "User Table"
$listObject.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
## auto size cols
$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Autofit() | Out-Null
##Save and exit the excel file
$filePathSave="E:\PowerShell_Dev\SQL_DUMP_PULLER\$Filename.xlsx"
$xl.SaveAs($filePathSave)
$xl.Close()
$xl.Quit()
```

And getting the following error.

> - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.
> - Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
> - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Is there is any code that I need to append to resolve this error?

Comment: *"getting the following error"* ... where?

Comment: This is the error which i'm getting and the data corresponding to this was not populated in Excel.   

1. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.
2.Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.
3.Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: I was able to read that just fine when you wrote it the first time. **Where** are you getting those errors? **Which statement** in your code is raising them?

Comment: Exactly in the for each loop. While returning the data from the database which is of double, int, etc and converting it to string during entering in excel sheet. The err occurred.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please show the complete, unaltered error messages.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.
At E:\PowerShell_Dev\SQL_DUMP_PULLER\DUMP_PULLER.ps1:40 char:25
+ ...             $ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowCount,$ColCount).Value2 =  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException



Please refer above - Unaltered Error Message thrown in PowerShell ISE

Comment: Line 40 in the code you posted is `$listObject.Name = "User Table"`. Please show either your actual code or the error message from the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I have some comment lines in the actual program, i have removed those unwanted comment lines and post my script here. But in my script the line 40 point to following ps code.

`$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowCount,$ColCount).Value2 = $r.ItemArray[$i-1]`